# Change images initial width in a "before and after" wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, image, plugins

On my website (which is under construction) I'm using "Before-After MultiX Slider". It's working fine, but I'm trying to have all the separators "collapsed" on the right (or left).

For example [here](http://woodydesign.it/prodotti-su-misura/armadi-mansarde-su-misura/)

I've tried to use css to change width of some classes as follows:

`.wmg-image.wmg-image-3.first.ui-resizable {
width: 91.6379%!important;
}`

`.wmg-image.wmg-image-2.ui-resizable {
width: 95%!important;
}`

`.wmg-image.wmg-image-1.ui-resizable {
width: 98.3621%!important;
}`

If I don't use `!important` nothing happens. If I use it, I get what I want
[image]
but the slider stops working and the images don't resize by scrolling separators.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find any failure there and digged a little deeper into the problem... Therefore I post a second answer, because the nature of the problem is somehow different after all, the code is working but not as expected for the following reason:

If you load scripts async the page will continue to render while the scripts are still loading, so it is possible that other none async scripts comming afterwards will start to load earlier than some async ones still in query...
Here we don't have async ones, BUT it seems to be like even if the async keyword is not present though the scripts will come in the query one after an other depending on their order nevertheless the server will load round about 3 or 4 scripts parallel!

-> So it happens that shorter scripts may be finished to load before longer ones allthough they've started to load later...

On my research I could not find a definite solution for that problem, because it simply seems to be quite hard to control that loading process in detail! (You i.e. can find some topics about that phenomena here on the board...)

I will present some different approaches, you will have to test them yourself, because I don't have that slider PlugIn so I could try:

Solution 1:

Try to use the "defer" keyword, this should be so to say the opposite of "async" and cause scripts to be not loaded before the page is parsed completly, but sadly I'm not sure if that works, never used it before and it sounds like it is the same as using "document.ready" which is not working in this case...
Important thing is that you must insert the script externally otherwise the keyword won't do anything, i.e:

```
 <script src="demo_defer.js" defer></script>
```

Solution 2:

A surely working solution would be to add our script as a callback to the call of the slider script, but I guess that this is no suitable solution here because you'll have to change the PlugIn code which is not update safe!

Solution 3:

Maybe you can play with a timeout to make sure that the execution will start later, but the problem is that you cannot really know how long this timeout must be! (i.e. have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

WORKAROUND:

I thought up a way to get around that problem, but as said before the code is untested, maybe try that and give me a notice when you have included this script, so I can have a look how it works...

In this way it is supposed that a class which does the positioning with the !important-statement is added and then removed on the first click, just then the elements are positioned again without !important and of course after that on every further click the positioning won't be manipulated again!

```
function sr_custom_width_for_slides() 
{ ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .notClicked .wmg-image.wmg-image-3.first.ui-resizable {
            width: 91.6379% !important;
        }
        .notClicked .wmg-image.wmg-image-2 {
            width: 95% !important;
        }
        .notClicked .wmg-image.wmg-image-3 {
            width: 98.3621% !important;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
            var firstClicked = false;

            jQuery(".wmg-before-after").addClass("notClicked");

            jQuery(".wmg-before-after").click(function() {
                if ( !firstClicked ) {
                    jQuery(".wmg-image.wmg-image-3.first.ui-resizable").css("width","91.6379%");
                    jQuery(".wmg-image.wmg-image-2.ui-resizable").css("width","95%");
                    jQuery(".wmg-image.wmg-image-1.ui-resizable").css("width","98.3621%");

                    jQuery(".wmg-before-after").removeClass("notClicked");

                    firstClicked = true;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php }
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'sr_custom_width_for_slides', 1000 );
```

EDIT REGARDING YOUR LAST COMMENT:

I checked the site again and in my case it sadly does not work at all, because the click event is never fired! I guess that the JS code of the PlugIn binds some events which maybe stop our script from working... (See the function "stopPropagation()" for more infos.) So my final clue is to simply bind another event which hopefully is not manipulated by the PlugIN in that way! As far as I can see this could be "mouseenter" or "mouseover"...

So just change

```
jQuery(".wmg-before-after").click(function() {
                ...
            });
```

to

```
jQuery(".wmg-before-after").mouseover(function() {
                ...
            });
```

Comment: Hi @ToTaTaRi. First of all, let me thank you for your interest and efforts. I've tried this code, and as with the previous one, the script is right there but not working.

I've also tried the solution 1 (with the external script) but it doesn't work either.

This thing is driving me mad. I will give a try to solution 3 as soon as possible.

Comment: I'm really sorry, the last code seems to work, but there is a stupid SYNTAX ERROR, pls delete the dot before the class name -> ".notClicked" must be "notClicked"!!! I changed the Code above... :)

Comment: Thank @ToTaTaRi ! This finally worked! There is just a "small issue". Because as soon as the images are loaded, the slider doesn't work. I have to click on one separator (the second or the last) and wait a little bit to make it work properly. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Ok, it's really a quite tricky problem, but I can't live with leaving it unsolved anymore... :D Now the point seems to be that the click event does not work properly! I don't really know exactly why, but have some ideas about that causes too... In general it is often a problem with PlugINs that you don't get 100% control over the code and many JS scripts together nearly never work totally stable! I've edited my answer again and hope that these changes will finally solve the whole prob... :)

Comment: Amazing. Now is working at full steam! Thanks a lot @ToTaTaRi !

Comment: Your welcome, the problem reallly cought my interest, that's why I got into it so much. I'm a wordpress developer, master in css, good in php, but not that practiced in JS... So it was a great opportunity to learn some things about the interaction of scripts and their loading process and so on... And I simply hate unsolved problems! :D

Answer (score 0):

the problem is quite simple... The width is set inline via js, so this will override any changes you made in your css file!

If you set the styles with an !important-statement it will work, but the sliders script cannot set the new width anymore...

So after all the most easy way to achieve what you want is to insert a small script which sets the styles AFTER the slider scripts have been loaded, so maybe at the very bottom of the footer of the page after the "wp_footer" call, because most plug ins enter their js over this hook, somehow like this:

```
<script>
jQuery(function() { 
    jQuery(".wmg-image.wmg-image-3.first.ui-resizable").css("width","91.6379%");
    jQuery(".wmg-image.wmg-image-2.ui-resizable").css("width","95%");
    jQuery(".wmg-image.wmg-image-1.ui-resizable").css("width","98.3621%");
});
</script>
```

I can't test it, but I'm quite sure that this will work, if the script is inserted at the correct position! :)

EDIT: I made a quick test via the console of the FF inspector and it works as expected, but as mentioned above, if the slider script will load later than this script it won't work at all!

Comment: Thank you @ToTaTaRi. Unfortunately it looks like the slider script is loaded after the footer, because it doesn't work.

Comment: If you add it in the Child Themes function.php it should be enough... the other scripts Must Be loaded in the Footer as it Seems When you have a Look at the Code in the Inspektor... Maybe the Problem is that they are loaded async, so the loading Progress May Start First, but end last! Have you checked weather the Script is Inserted and at the Right Position, or if there are Any errors? I cant Check Right Now, because im online just on my phone at the Moment...

Comment: I've added it in the Child Theme's function.php file, but it doesn't work. The code is in the right position: https://snag.gy/3IqBwM.jpg